# Do processes have a stack, or are only the threads that actually have stack

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, stack

I am learning about operating systems and while learning about processes the book mentions that the process has a stack. Later the book compares processes and threads, listing some properties of each. In this section it mentions that each thread has a stack, but it doesn't mention the process having a stack. So does the process have a stack or not?

Comment: Usually a process starts out as a single thread with some extra bookkeeping data. So a process itself has no stack, but its sole thread definitely does.

Comment: so the process' "stack region" in memory is actually the place where the process holds the stack of every thread it possesses?

Comment: No. The process's "stack region" is the stack region of the first thread of the process.

Comment: why does a process start as a single thread?

Comment: The options are: start with a single thread, or none. Depending on the OS implementation, the initial thread might be provided for all processes by default (that's the case on unices, typically), or it may have to be explicitly instantiated by whatever thread wishes to start a new process.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica
`No. The process's "stack region" is the stack region of the first thread of the process.` Is it really true?. Because multiple threads share same parent process's address space,  I think `process stack region is is actually the place where the process holds the all stacks of every thread it possesses` is correct.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on whose definition of a process you follow.

As "process" was defined in early Unix, each process implicitly had one thread of execution, so the process had a stack.

OSes that support multiple threads per process (OS/2, Win32, post stone-age Unix, Linux, etc.) normally treat stacks as belonging to threads. In this case, a process normally consists of one or more threads, so a process *indirectly* owns at least one stack, but quite possibly more.